# The placement of utility classes in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm trying to figure out where to put my utility classes in a DDD based project.  The case is a follows:

I have a class called CookieAwareWebClient which is required for the core to work. Form what I've read online this seems like a class that belongs in the Infrastructure tier, however one is not supposed to refer to the Infrastructure tier from the Core tier. This means that I cannot place functionality that the Core tier depends on in the Infrastructure tier. Where then should this CookieAwareWebClient class be placed?

Comment: The name sounds clearly to be part of the infrastructure. Without further knowledge of your code and application I would say that you have a design problem when your core depends on this class.

Comment: @Jehof The dependency on this class stems from a service class in the Core tier that retrieves data from an API and returns said data to the calling application. I figured that a repository would only be excessive in this case. What do you think?

Comment: So the CookieAwareWebClient is used to call an external service that your core depends on. Is that right?

Comment: That is correct. It is used to connect to an API and returns data from said API. The service in my core is basically a wrapper for this API.

Comment: What's the relationship between your domain model and this service? Usually, you would declare an interface in your domain model and implement it in the infrastructure layer, just like with the repository pattern (that's the Dependency Inversion Principle). Such services are usually consumed by the application services, not the domain. For instance, a repository is rarely used from an entity. When you can, let the application layer resolve the dependencies, but if that isin't pratical you can always inject services into entities at the method level. Using interface segregation helps.

Answer (score 1):

Without understanding exactly what you need to do, I believe that @plalx sums it up in the comments:

- Establish an interface which provides the functionality that your Core tier requires
- Implement this interface in CookieAwareWebClient
- Use Dependency Inversion to allow the Core to use CookieAwareWebClient

Here's some code (C# in this case) with constructor injection as an example:

The interface:

```
namespace Core
{
  public interface IBlah
  {
    int SomethingCoreNeeds();
  }
}
```

The implementation by CookieAwareWebClient:

```
namespace Services
{
  public class CookieAwareWebClient : IBlah
  {
    // ... rest of class 
    private int _somethingCookieAwareWebClientHasThatCoreNeeds;

    public int SomethingCoreNeeds()
    {
      return _somethingCookieAwareWebClientHasThatCoreNeeds;
    }
    // ... rest of class 
  }
}
```

The consuming service in your Core:

```
namespace Core
{
  public class DomainService
  {
    private readonly IBlah _blah;

    public DomainService(IBlah blah)
    {
      _blah = blah;
    }

    public void DoSomething(DomainEntity entity)
    {
      entity.NeededValue = _blah.SomethingCoreNeeds();
    }
  }
}
```